# VBA web Scraping - Shifting HTMLdoc to XML but facing errors while clicking on a button

Tags: html, xml, vba, web-scraping, xslt

I have an `MSHTML.HTMLDocument` code that:

1. Opens the page `"https://www.ksestocks.com/HistoryHighLow"`
2. Fills an input i.e `786`
3. Then click on a button to fetch a table
4. There I catch a row and its 4 children using the following code

   ```
   Sub KSE_GetHTMLDocument()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDOC As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLClasses As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLClass As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCel As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim colNum, rowNum, RowN, C As Integer

    Dim Cel As Range

    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate "https://www.ksestocks.com/HistoryHighLow"

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    For Each Cel In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If IsEmpty(Cel.Value) = False Then

        Set HTMLDOC = IE.Document
        Set HTMLInput = HTMLDOC.getElementById("selscrip")

        HTMLInput.Value = Trim(Cel.Value)
        Debug.Print Cel.Value
        HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click

        While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        C = 0
        For Each HTMLClass In HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If InStr(HTMLClass.innerText, "Last 3 years (") > 0 Then
                If Left(HTMLClass.innerText, 14) = "Last 3 years (" Then
                        For Each HTMLCel In HTMLClass.Children
                            Debug.Print HTMLCel.innerText
                            If C = 1 Then
                            Cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = HTMLCel.innerText
                            ElseIf C = 2 Then
                            Cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = HTMLCel.innerText
                            ElseIf C = 3 Then
                            Cel.Offset(0, 9).Value = HTMLCel.innerText
                            ElseIf C = 4 Then
                            Cel.Offset(0, 10).Value = HTMLCel.innerText
                            End If
                            C = C + 1
                        Next
                End If
            End If
        Next
   End If
   Next    
   End Sub
   ```

The above code is working fine getting values from the website, but when I change the code to shift it to `XML` it stops working also internet explorer is popping up with no results every time with a new window.

where I am doing it wrong?

Is there more robust way of scraping webpage?

**Please check the following code before running**

```
Sub KSE_Get_XML()
    
    Dim XMLp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDOC As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
    Dim HTMLClasses As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLClass As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
    Dim HTMLCel As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
    Dim colNum, rowNum, RowN, C As Integer
    
    XMLp.Open "GET", "https://www.ksestocks.com/HistoryHighLow", False
    XMLp.send
    
    HTMLDOC.body.innerHTML = XMLp.responseText
    
    Dim Cel As Range
    
 '   Do While HTMLDOC.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
  '  Loop
    
    For Each Cel In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    If IsEmpty(Cel.Value) = False Then
        
        HTMLDOC.body.innerHTML = XMLp.responseText
        Set HTMLInput = HTMLDOC.getElementById("selscrip")

        HTMLInput.Value = Trim(Cel.Value)
        Debug.Print Cel.Value
        HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Click
        
        'Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
       '' Do While HTMLDOC.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
       '     DoEvents
      '  Loop

        C = 0
        For Each HTMLClass In HTMLDOC.getElementsByTagName("tr")
            If InStr(HTMLClass.innerText, "Last 3 years (") > 0 Then
                If Left(HTMLClass.innerText, 14) = "Last 3 years (" Then
                        For Each HTMLCel In HTMLClass.Children
                            Debug.Print HTMLCel.innerText
                            If C = 1 Then
                            Cel.Offset(0, 7).Value = HTMLCel.innerText
                            ElseIf C = 2 Then
                            Cel.Offset(0, 8).Value = HTMLCel.innerText
                            ElseIf C = 3 Then
                            Cel.Offset(0, 9).Value = HTMLCel.innerText
                            ElseIf C = 4 Then
                            Cel.Offset(0, 10).Value = HTMLCel.innerText
                            End If
                            C = C + 1
                        Next
                End If
            End If
            
            
        Next
   End If
   Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of IE altogether and switch to xmlhttp requests, which is robust and less error prone. When you go for xhr, you need to issue a post http requests with appropriate parameters. This is something you can do to get the results right next to `Last 3 years (1 Sep 2018 - 1 Sep 2021)` from that table.

```
Public Sub GetContent()
    Const Url = "https://www.ksestocks.com/HistoryHighLow"
    Dim Http As Object, Html As HTMLDocument, Htmldoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim params$, I&, R&, ws As Worksheet, searchKeyword$
    
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument
    Set Htmldoc = New HTMLDocument
    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    R = 2
    
    searchKeyword = "786"   'you can use different search keywords here to get related results
    
    params = "selscrip=" & searchKeyword
    
    With Http
        .Open "POST", Url, False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36"
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .send (params)
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll("td.plain")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            If InStr(.item(I).innerText, "Last 3 years") > 0 Then
                Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = "<table>" & .item(I).ParentNode.outerHTML & "</table>"
                ws.Cells(R, 1) = Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("td.plain")(1).innerText
                ws.Cells(R, 2) = Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("td.plain")(2).innerText
                ws.Cells(R, 3) = Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("td.plain")(3).innerText
                ws.Cells(R, 4) = Htmldoc.querySelectorAll("td.plain")(4).innerText
            End If
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
1. Microsoft XML, v6.0
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Your search keyword would be what you see in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1Yzp.jpg).

Comment: If for some reason the script doesn't work for you, it will only be because the variation of our excel version. I'm using Microsoft Office 2013 by the way.